# Angular 2:How to detect the completion of HTTP request?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have following Http put request in Angular 2:

```
...
...
private Url='api/demo/'    
UpdatState(obj: Model) {
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });
        return this.http.put(this.Url + obj.Id, JSON.stringify(obj), { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json().data).subscribe(..);
    }
```

and a get service for same model:

```
 getState(){
  return this.http.get(this.Url)
        .map(response => response.json());        
}
```

Problem:
I have set up my component in such a manner that first put request occurs-which changes my table in Db. Immediately after that, get request occurs which gets the table entries. But, before the Put request completes, get completes its execution.

```
...
...    
onSomeEvent(){
    this.updatestate(obj);
    this.getState();
    }
...
...
```

How to detect whether my http request is completed in Angular 2?

**Edit**:
From the answer of @Gunter, I provided three call backs to my subscribe method of put:

```
UpdatState(obj: Model) {
     let headers = new Headers({
     Content-Type': 'application/json',
     });
     return this.http.put(this.Url + obj.Id, JSON.stringify(obj), { headers: headers })
.map(res => res.json().data)
.subscribe(
    (a) => { this.b = a }, //b is my local array
    err => { this.error = err; }, //error is my local string variable
    () => { this.completed(); }
    );
}
```

And my completed method is:

```
 completed(){
alert("Request completed");
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass three callbacks to `subscribe(...)`

```
this.http.put(...).subscribe(
  value => this.doSomething(value), // called for each value
  error => this.handleError(err),
  () => this.completed()
})
```

The last one is called when the observable is closed. Because `http.xxx()` always emits only one value and then closes the observable, the first and the last are pretty much the same.

There is also the `finally()` operator that is called in any case (success and error).

Comment: Isn't there any `interceptor` kind of thing in A2, which will give you handle on each request? I know its not related to question, though asking here, apology for the same :)

Comment: I have seen it mentioned in other questions but I don't know exactly what interceptors are. I haven't used Angular1. AFAIR usually -  creating your own `CustomHttp extends Http` and provide it instead of `Http` - was the answer.

Comment: Interceptor means, its an handle which somehow provide you control over before sending `http` request & after sending `http` request, generally cases where added removing custom `headers`, `transformRequest`, `transformResonse`, etc happens there, I got your point by doing `CustomHttp`  we can do it, but how that would have provide the control over each `http` request?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is completed() an inbuilt function or you mean to substitute my get method at the place of completed()? Sorry for my lame question but I am new to angular 2.

Comment: You can override the implementation of each method in `CustomHttp` and execute custom code before forwarding to the superclass implementation and modifying the parameters before forwarding them to the superclass.

Comment: @KaranDesai `doSomething()`, `handleError()` and `completed()` is just demo code. I updated my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Upon completion of request, it is not invoking my method I called at, in place of this.completed()...Any idea why?

Comment: Can you please update your question and add the code that demonstrates what you're doing?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: Is the first callback called (called for each value)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121721/discussion-between-karan-desai-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You were right. My first call back was not taken up...I dont know why, Now it's invoking my completed method in put too.Thanks

Comment: Probably the call did actually not complete maybe because of some server issue. Thanks for the feedback.